# IIS Directory Browser Customization

Tags: html, iis, directory-browsing

I need to add a link on the default IIS directory page... I have tried to setup a custom footer which would work but I cannot get it to display...

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by creating a custom HttpModule.

http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/01/21/Get-nice-looking-directory-listings-for-your-IIS-website-with-DirectoryListingModule.aspx

Comment: what version of IIS are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I created an ASP.NET MVC application for this purpose: [DirectoryListing](https://github.com/miratechcorp/DirectoryListing).